# Why does runing as sudo require LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT?

Tags: xorg, wayland, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I think I understand what LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT does, per this explanation: [What does LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1 actually do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/what-does-libgl-always-indirect-1-actually-do)

However I am having trouble understanding when/why it is needed?

In my case, I have a homegrown dotnet core application (using [Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net/How-It-Works) framework) which works fine on WSL2 Linux (Ubuntu Distro) when not run as sudo, but when running as sudo, it displays the window frame and no content. However specifying LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1 fixes the problem. So why would I be required to specify LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT only when running as sudo?

To summarize:

| command line | works? |
| --- | --- |
| ./myapp | yes |
| LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1 ./myapp | yes |
| sudo ./myapp | no |
| sudo LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1 ./myapp | yes |

sudo -E/-H do not seem to make a difference. The WSL distro Is Ubuntu 22.04, which seems to be using wayland.